# Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided () is is not a valid name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to spawn the DOM with some snowflakes.. I am getting this error in my console and no snowflakes.

*Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('< span id='flake0' style='cursor: default; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; user-select: none;position:absolute;top:-24'>• </ span>') is not a valid name.*

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong here.. PHPStorm is also not giving me any hints. I am looping through all my snowflakes and they get random sizes.

Here is my code:

```
var container = document.getElementById("js-container");

for (let i = 0; i <= snowMax; i++) {
    var content = document.createElement("<span id='flake" + i + "' style='" + snowStyles + "position:absolute;top:-" + snowMaxSize + "'>" + snowEntity + "</span>");
    container.appendChild(content);
}
```

I also tried escaping the span with backticks, but it's not helping..

Comment: It's always best to double-check the documentation when not getting the results you expect from a function. In this case, the best documentation is [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) (although you could also look at [the specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-document-createelement%E2%91%A0), it's more academic). `createElement` tags a **tag name** (like `"div"`), not HTML. See the linked question's answers for details.

Comment: If you want to append to an existing element (like `container`) providing the new content as HTML, you can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) for that: `container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "HTML goes here");`.